# how can i pass the querystring into aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

i have url like this : `DossierSoin_Fiche.aspx?SoinId=1`

how can i pass this SoinId    into  `dx:ASPxPopupControl`

`<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupControl_Surveill"

ContentUrl="~/PopUp/Surveillance.aspx?SoinId=<%=SoinId %>"` ?

thanks you in advance

PS : i can not use code behinde, because it will reload the page, then i will lost the data that have not save in database. I use callback instead, so i need pass this querystring value on aspx not in aspx.cs

Comment: you can access that in `page_load` event and set contenturl from there

Comment: Can't you assign ASPxPopupControl .ContentUrl in code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

make a property "SoinID" (if you dont already have one)

```
protected string SoinId  {get;set;}
```

(type of modifier is up to the OP, could also be `public`).

then, assign a value to the property in your `page_load`:

```
SoinId = Request.QueryString["SoinID"];
```

your .aspx code can stay the same if you use it like this.

Comment: I would use the protected modifier instead of public.

Comment: thanks you but i got : The format of the input string is incorrect

Comment: what exactly is your querystring ? is it something like "13" (i mean: is it a number?), or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

In your containers codebehind:

```
protected string SoinId
{
   get
   {
      return Request["SoinId"];
   }
}
```

And use the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value to the public property in the CodeBehind of the page.

```
ASPxPopupControl_Surveill.ContentUrl = ...
```

[edit made with thanks to rs.]

Comment: I think he already has a property contenturl that he wants to set value for

Comment: Even better, just pass it then. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Option A:

1) Declare a protected variable named SoinId in the scope of your aspx page.

2) In the Page_Load event, add this:

```
if(!Request.QueryString["SoinId"]==null)
{
   SoinId = Request.QueryString["SoinId"];
}
```

Opetion B:

Replace your aspx code with this:

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupControl_Surveill" 
ContentUrl="~/PopUp/Surveillance.aspx?SoinId=<%=Request.QueryString["SoinId"] %>">
```

Edit: Consider using a property as other colleagues proposed. It's more ellegant.

Comment: this is VB.NET, the OP's question is tagged *C#*

Comment: thanks you but i got : The format of the input string is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could just assign the value in the code behind.

e.g.;

```
ASPxPopupControl_Surveill.ContentUrl = "~/PopUp/Surveillance.aspx?SoinId=" + Request["SoinId"].ToString();
```